# UNION CTE with ORDER BY on 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is not easy to explain, however, I do believe there is a much nicer way to do what I managed to do and hope to get some help.

I have 3 tables (`T1`, `T2`, and `T3`). I need to get the latest from `T1` and `T2`, then with those results return the results from `t3` or from the previous result if `t3` is empty. So the `LatestDate` doesn't really matter if there is a record in `t3`. Also, if there is no data in `t3` and the `LatestDate` is the same on `t1` and `t2` (rarely will happen, but want to plan accordingly), I want results from `t1`.

Here's a sample of what I got, mind you the actual query is has many more fields, but the concept is the same.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t1](
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [LatestDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t2](
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [LatestDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t3](
    [Id] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [LatestDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
);
INSERT t1 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t1 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2001-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t1 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2002-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t2 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2001-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t2 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2002-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t2 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2003-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t3 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2001-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t3 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2000-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
INSERT t3 (Id, LatestDate) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2004-01-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime));
GO;

WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
        SELECT 2 AS Sort, * FROM t1 WHERE t1.id = @UserId
        UNION
        SELECT 3 AS Sort, * FROM t2 WHERE t2.id = @UserId
    ) AS t
    ORDER BY
        t.LatestDate DESC
)
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM CTE
    UNION
    SELECT 1 AS Sort, * FROM t3 WHERE t3.id = @UserId
) AS t
ORDER BY
    t.Sort;
```

Expected results:

```
When @UserID = 1: 

    Sort    Source    Id    LatestDate
    1       t3        1     1/1/2001

When @UserID = 2: 

    Sort    Source    Id    LatestDate
    1       t3        2     1/1/2000

When @UserID = 3: 

    Sort    Source    Id    LatestDate
    2       t1        3     1/1/2002

When @UserID = 4: 

    Sort    Source    Id    LatestDate
    3       t2        4     1/1/2003

When @UserID = 5: 

    Sort    Source    Id    LatestDate
    1       t3        5     1/1/2004
```

Thanks!

Comment: I ran your query and get the expected results.. I couldn't understood what you want to know. Do you want to konw if there's a better way to do the same? Question: What SGBD are you using? (sql-server..., version?, or other)

Comment: @RMH is here an easier/nicer way to write that query? It seems like a lot of Select Top 1 everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want something like:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT  = 5;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS src, 1 as [tbl], * FROM  t1 WHERE id = @UserId
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, * FROM t2 WHERE id = @UserId
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, * FROM t3 WHERE id = @UserId
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY src DESC, LatestDate DESC, tbl ASC) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT Id, LatestDate
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[RextesterDemo](http://rextester.com/JCC61406)**

---

Using `PARTITION BY` you could move filtering `@userId` to final part:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT  = 5;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS src, 1 as [tbl], * FROM  t1 
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 2, * FROM t2 
    UNION ALL SELECT 3, 3, * FROM t3 
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT *
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY src DESC, LatestDate DESC, tbl ASC) AS rn
    FROM cte
)
SELECT Id, LatestDate
FROM cte2
WHERE rn = 1
  AND id = @UserID
```

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/QJVV35726)**

Comment: Thanks! This actually works great so far! I'll check this against the actual query now.

Comment: Demo1 vs Demo2, are there any performance considerations i need to take ? I assume Demo1 is better since it will filter out the data first by `@UserId2`

Comment: Sorry, I updated question because it's missing just one fore thing. If no data is in `t3` and `LatestDate` is the same on both `t1` and `t2t`, then I want results from `t1`. I assume i can do `OVER(ORDER BY src DESC, LatestDate DESC, COL ASC) AS rn` and add a `col` to each result?

Comment: I was able to confirm the results with a little modification to your code. Thanks!

Comment: I updated your answer with what i did, but i did not modify your Rextester demos.

Comment: @RoLYroLLs Glad to hear that I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

This assumes you will take the t3 result if it exists 
or the max result from T1 or T2 if not.

```
if exists(select * from t3 where ID= @ID)
(
  select ID, Max(LatestDate), TN='T3' 
  from t3 
  where ID= @ID
)
else
(
  select top 1 ID, Max(LatestDate) LD,TN
  from (Select *,TN='t1' from T1
        union all
        Select *, TN='t2' from t2) as a
  where id=@ID
  group by ID,TN
  order by LD desc
)
```

Comment: Hi, sorry. After running this i get completely different results than expected. Am i missing something?

Comment: I guess I really did read your question all the way through. Can I sum it up like this: Use t3 is value exists otherwise you MAX from t1 or t2?

Comment: altered answer to use if and exists

Comment: This works and I like to give credit for it. However, I'm leaning towards Lad's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45336054/286618) as it's all in one statement.